# Define route that is preferred "always"

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ipv6, ipv4

I'm currently implementing an IPv6 only service. Since it should also be consumed using IPv4, I'm implementing a translator.

In the translator server, I need to add a route to a different netns to be properly translated. The problem I'm having is the preferred route is to go via `lo` interface, instead of using my specific route entry.

Imagine a scenario where 4 devices are connected to the same vlan like this:

```
Gateway (192.168.132.1) --------------|----------|
Server (192.168.132.85) --------------|Switch    |
Translator (192.168.132.87) ----------|same vLan |
Firewall (service 2001:db8:1::44) ----|----------|
```

*Note: The server and the translator are virtual machines (VMWare), in case this is important.*

All the devices have defined a `/24` mask on it's IPv4 interface.

**Scenario that works**

Define on Gateway a route like this:

```
ip -4 route add 192.168.132.95/32 via 192.168.132.87
```

From the Internet it prefers that route instead of using its directly connected interface to the same network segment, because the `/32` mask is more specific than the interface `/24` mask. The `tcpdump` demonstrates the traffic goes to the translator, and from there it is translated into IPv6 and goes to the firewall like it should. No problem there.

The drawback is it only applies when the traffic comes from the internet, but if the traffic comes from the firewall (to reach another service, for example) it doesn't work. It should be necesary to define the same route in the firewall. And also should be done in the Server in case the server needs to use the same service. It's hard to maintain.

**Scenario that DOESN'T work**

The best solution would be to make the translator to "answer" to `192.168.132.95` requests instead of doing it in any other device. The problem is the translator has hard-coded to ignore packets whose destination addresses match one of the interfaces of the namespace it's translating in.

So, I decided to use a new namespace. Easy, Right?

Well, haven't been able to get it to work.

I have this script for testing that I constructed based on [this document](https://www.jool.mx/en/node-based-translation.html).
The difference is that the document's goal is to reach from the inside of the left side server to the right one and I want to reach the translator form anywhere.

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1: Create the virtual interfaces and the new namespace
    ip netns add joolns
    ip link add name to_jool type veth peer name to_world
    ip link set up dev to_jool
    ip link set dev to_world netns joolns
    ip netns exec joolns ip link set up dev to_world

#2: Determine link-local addresses of veth pair (used as nexthops later)
    LL_TO_JOOL=$(ip -6 -br address show scope link dev to_jool | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')
    LL_TO_WORLD=$(ip netns exec joolns ip -6 -br address show scope link dev to_world | awk '{print $3}' | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')


#3: Set up IP addressing and routing inside the Jool namespace
    ip netns exec joolns ip -6 route add default via $LL_TO_JOOL dev to_world
    ip netns exec joolns ip -4 address add 192.168.0.2/24 dev to_world

#4: Set up IP addressing and routing in the global namespace

    #IPv4:
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ens224/proxy_ndp

    #IPv6:
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/ens256/proxy_ndp

    ### DOESN'T WORK USING proxy JUST DON'T ANSWER PING
    #if (ip neigh show proxy | grep 192.168.132.95); then
    #    ip -4 neigh del proxy 192.168.132.95 dev ens256
    #fi
    #ip -4 neigh add proxy 192.168.132.95 dev ens256

    ### DOESN'T WORK USING arp -s JUST DON'T ANSWER PING
    #if (arp -a | grep 192.168.132.95); then
    #    arp -d 192.168.132.95
    #fi
    #arp -s 192.168.132.95 $(ip a show ens256 |grep ether | awk '{print $2}')

    #HAD TO CONFIGURE 192.168.132.95 DIRECTLY IN THE ens256 INTERFACE 
    #USING nmtui. tcpdump shows ARP requests, but never capture any answer
    #even without any jool configuration, and doing "modprobe -r jool_siit"
    #with the nmtui configuration was the only way packets reached the translator

    ip -4 address add 192.168.0.1/24 dev to_jool
    ip -4 route add 192.168.132.95/32 via 192.168.0.1 dev to_jool  #<<<<<*****

    echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*/forwarding

#5: Fire up Jool inside joolns
    modprobe jool_siit

    ip netns exec joolns sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
    ip netns exec joolns sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1

    ip netns exec joolns jool_siit instance  add --netfilter --pool6 fd79:db8:ee00::/96
    ip netns exec joolns jool_siit eamt add 192.168.132.95 2001:db8:1::44
```

It generates a separate network namespace where the translator is running, so it should work.

The thing is no packets go to the translator. Not even because of the route (with `<<<<<*****` comment above)

If I check what route is used, it always begins with `lo` interface:

```
[root@srv ~]# ip route get 200.33.163.95
local 192.168.132.95 dev lo src 192.168.132.87
    cache <local>
[root@srv ~]#
```

I can see incoming packets for `192.168.132.95`, but I never see packets going to `2001:db8:1::44`, nor going to `to_jool` interface.

If I don't configure `192.168.132.95` using nmtui and instead use `arp -s` or `ip -4 neigh add proxy`, I only see ARP requests, like this:

```
[root@srv ~]# tcpdump -n -l -i ens256 "host 192.168.132.85"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens256, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
22:38:16.418578 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.132.95 tell 192.168.132.85, length 46
22:38:18.415886 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.132.95 tell 192.168.132.85, length 46
22:38:19.418514 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.132.95 tell 192.168.132.85, length 46
22:38:20.420487 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.132.95 tell 192.168.132.85, length 46

4 packets captured
4 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
[root@srv ~]#
```

If anybody needs more information, just tell me.

Does anyone has ideas about how to fix this?.

How can I verify where the received packets are going and why `192.168.132.95/32` via `192.168.0.1` is never used (AFAIK)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking to do something similar to this, here I will leave what I've learned.

First of all, to answer the original question, Linux can do [PBR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) and even if there is a default rule to deliver locally to addresses directly configured to the network interface, you can change that and add a routing table before local delivery.

To do that you can do the following

```
# To override the default priority since it's needed to route local IP's
    ip rule add preference 1000 lookup local
    ip rule delete preference 0
```

Then, you can create rules with preference lower than 1000 and routing tables attached to them. Those will be processed before the local delivery ones like this

```
ip rule add from all to 1.2.3.4/24 priority 100 table 23
```

Second and most important thing is: The translator doesn't know anything about routing. In fact, you can define Explicit Address Mappings Table (EAMT) entries of different networks without a problem in the same instance, so no need to use multiple network namespaces as long as the OS can comunícate with all origins and destinations. (Thank you @ydahhrk:ungleich.ch at [matrix.ungleich.ch](https://matrix.ungleich.ch/)

Third: How to make sure the return packets use the right path.

I have two Internet service providers and have different addresses on each one.

This works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

#RESET PREVIOUSLY CREATED TABLES
ip route flush table 102 #> /dev/null 2>&1
ip rule del table 102 #> /dev/null 2>&1

ip route flush table 103 #> /dev/null 2>&1
ip rule del table 103 #> /dev/null 2>&1

#RESET TO DEFAULTS
ip rule flush > /dev/null 2>&1
ip rule add from all lookup local pref 0 > /dev/null 2>&1
ip rule add from all lookup main pref 32766 > /dev/null 2>&1
ip rule add from all lookup default pref 32767 > /dev/null 2>&1

ip route add default via 203.0.113.0.1 table 102
ip route add 203.0.113.0.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 203.0.113.0.123 table 102
ip rule add from 203.0.113.0.0/24 to all pref 102 table 102
ip rule add from all to 203.0.113.0.0/24 pref 102 table 102

ip route add default via 200.200.200.0.1 table 103
ip route add 200.200.200.0.0/24 dev ens256 proto kernel scope link src 200.200.200.0.123 table 103
ip rule add from 200.200.200.0.0/24 to all pref 103 table 103
ip rule add from all to 200.200.200.0.0/24 pref 103 table 103
```